# Rails 4 first_or_initialize sql double id "_id_id" sql generated by Arel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, arel

I have a simple Rails 4 first_or_initialize that is creating entries in a rich join table as per the annotation on the tender.rb file below.

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: tenders
#
#  id                 :integer          not null, primary key
#  project_id         :integer          not null
#  company_id         :integer          not null
#  tender_awarded_at  :date
#
# Indexes
#
#  index_tenders_on_company_id          (company_id)
#  index_tenders_on_project_id          (project_id)

class Tender < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project_id
  belongs_to :company_id
end

csv = CSV.new(data, {headers: true, header_converters: :symbol, col_sep: ','})
  csv.each do |line|
    unless line[:project_id].blank?
      project_id = line[:project_id].to_i
      company_id = line[:company_id].to_i
      tender = ::Tender.where(:project => project_id, :company => company_id).first_or_initialize
```

This script works fine for other imports that are importing by only matching one primary key. This one is creating by matching two non-primary key columns.

```
PG::UndefinedColumn at /imports/tender
ERROR:  column tenders.project_id_id does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT  "tenders".* FROM "tenders" WHERE "tenders"."project
```

It looks like the sql is being set by a name in the Arel @value instance variable. I can't see it anywhere before this point.

```
<Arel::Nodes::Equality:0x007f8dd0d22318 @left=#<struct Arel::Attributes::Attribute relation=#<Arel::Table:0x007f8dd0ccb6d0 @name="tenders", @engine=Tender(id: integer, project_id: integer, company_id: integer, tender_awarded_at: date), @columns=nil, @aliases=[], @table_alias=nil, @primary_key=nil>, name="project_id_id">
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: could you add the associations from the model

Comment: Hmm that prompted me to look at the relationships on `tender.rb` which I have just added to the question. Which I can see now I have added `belongs_to :project_id` instead of `belongs_to :projects`. That is probably the reason. I'll suss it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Tender < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project_id
  belongs_to :company_id
end
```

That's your problem there, you don't point to columns, you point to model/classes, the correct way would be

```
class Tender < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :company
end
```

Always try to read those associations as english, it will make sense, here's some examples

```
belongs_to :project # cause it's one
has_one :project
has_many :projects # cause it's many
```

Comment: I both love and hate when the answer is so stupidly easy :) Thanks for your second set of eyes.